Selenium automation script
I'm building a script that automates going through a survey for work. I build surveys and I'm trying to create a script that checks that the surveys I build are working. Everything is fine up to a point where it simply crashes. I can't even tell from where. I keep having different errors occurring. The most recent is running into a stale error when working with multi_grid questions. I suspect it relates to the dom refreshing.
The script creates a question type dictionary and if it runs into any of the dictionary questions it runs a sequence of entries and clicks.
My issue is occuring when running into multi_grid questions where the element is not being clicked and it crashes. The process is the same as single_grid, but it will select more than one random element.
def start_testing():
    try:
        str_base_url = entry_url.get()
        int_num_tests = int(entry_tests.get())

        if not str_base_url or int_num_tests <= 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter both a valid URL and a positive 
        number of respondents.")
            return

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        action = ActionChains(driver)

        for i in range(1, int_num_tests + 1):
            str_test_url = f"{str_base_url}&altid=myj_trial_27_{i}"
            driver.get(str_test_url)

            # Switch to the first iframe (index 0)
            try:
                driver.switch_to.frame(0)  # Switch to the first iframe by index
            except NoSuchFrameException:
                print("Survey iframe not found.")
                continue

            while True:
                # Check if last page (completion page) is reached
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lastPageText"))
                    )
                    print(f"Test {i}/{int_num_tests} complete.")
                    break  # End the test for this respondent
                except TimeoutException:
                    pass  # Continue if last page is not reached

                # Locate question elements inside the iframe
                lst_cCheck = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cCheck")
                lst_cRadio = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cRadio")
                lst_cTextInput = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cTextInput")
                lst_cTextArea = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cTextArea")
                lst_cFInput = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cFInput")
                lst_cBtnSingleGrid = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  "//div[@id='SingleGridQ_btn']/div/div/div/p")
                lst_cBtnMultiGrid = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MultiGridQ_btn']/div/div/p")
                lst_cSay = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cSay")
                lst_dropdowns = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "n0A")  # Locate dropdowns

                # Store non-empty question types
                dict_question_types = {
                    "multi_select": lst_cCheck,
                    "single_select": lst_cRadio,
                    "short_text": lst_cTextInput,
                    "long_text": lst_cTextArea,
                    "numeric_input": lst_cFInput,
                    "single_select_grid": lst_cBtnSingleGrid,
                    "dropdown": lst_dropdowns,
                    "multi_select_grid": lst_cBtnMultiGrid
                }
                dict_question_types = {k: v for k, v in dict_question_types.items() if v}

                # Interact with question types if they exist
                if dict_question_types:
                    str_selected_type = random.choice(list(dict_question_types.keys()))
                    obj_elements = dict_question_types[str_selected_type]

                    if str_selected_type == "multi_select":
                        # Randomly select up to the total number of checkboxes
                        int_num_checks = random.randint(1, len(obj_elements))
                        for obj_checkbox in random.sample(obj_elements, int_num_checks):
                            action.click(obj_checkbox).perform()

                    elif str_selected_type == "single_select":
                        obj_random_radio = random.choice(obj_elements)
                        action.click(obj_random_radio).perform()

                    elif str_selected_type == "short_text":
                        obj_text_input = random.choice(obj_elements)
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", obj_text_input, str_short_text)

                    elif str_selected_type == "long_text":
                        obj_text_area = random.choice(obj_elements)
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", obj_text_area, str_long_text)

                    elif str_selected_type == "numeric_input":
                        for obj_numeric_input in obj_elements:
                            random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
                            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", obj_numeric_input, random_number)

                    elif str_selected_type == "single_select_grid":
                        # Keep selecting and clicking .cBtnSingleGrid until there are no more available
                        while obj_elements:
                            obj_grid_option = random.choice(obj_elements)
                            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", obj_grid_option)
                            # Refresh the list of grid options after clicking
                            obj_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='SingleGridQ_btn']/div/div/div/p")

                        print("All single grid options have been selected.")

                    elif str_selected_type == "multi_select_grid":
                        # Randomly select multiple grid options
                        while obj_elements:
                            int_num_checks = random.randint(1, len(obj_elements))
                            selected_options = random.sample(obj_elements, int_num_checks)
                            for obj_grid_option in selected_options:
                                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", obj_grid_option)
                                obj_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MultiGridQ_btn']/div/div/p")

                            # Click the Next button after each selection set
                            try:
                                btn_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnNext"))
                                )
                                action.click(btn_next).perform()
                            except TimeoutException:
                                print("Next button not found or not clickable.")
                                break
                            # Refresh the list of grid options after clicking Next
                            obj_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MultiGridQ_btn']/div/div/p")

                        print("All multi-select grid options have been selected.")

                    elif str_selected_type == "dropdown":
                        for dropdown in obj_elements:
                            # Click the dropdown to expand it
                            dropdown.click()
                            # Wait for options to be available
                            time.sleep(0.5)  # Optional delay to allow options to load
                            # Locate the options within the dropdown
                            options = dropdown.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")
                            # Filter out options with a value of -1
                            valid_options = [option for option in options if option.get_attribute("value") != "-1"]
                            if valid_options:
                                # Select a random option from the filtered list
                                random_option = random.choice(valid_options)
                                random_option.click()

                    # After processing the question types, click the Next button
                    try:
                        if str_selected_type != "single_select_grid" and str_selected_type != "multi_select_grid":
                            btn_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnNext"))
                            )
                            action.click(btn_next).perform()
                            continue  # Move to the next page
                    except TimeoutException:
                        print("Next button not found or not clickable.")
                        break

                # If no question types are available but .cSay exists, click 'Next'
                elif lst_cSay:
                    try:
                        btn_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnNext"))
                        )
                        action.click(btn_next).perform()
                        continue  # Move to the next page
                    except TimeoutException:
                        print("Next button not found or not clickable.")
                        break

                # If neither question types nor .cSay are present, break out
                else:
                    print("No actionable elements found.")
                    break


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        driver.quit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Completed", f"Tested {int_num_tests} survey links.")
        root.destroy()


If it's crashing and you can't tell from where, remove all of your try-excepts and run it. The error message will tell you exactly where it's crashing. Other than that, we can't do much for you without the URL.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
